# How do I use the drive.file scope for a standalone google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have a standalone script that uses the Sheets API. There are only two calls:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getSheetByName("Answers")
SpreadsheetApp.openById(otherspreadsheetID).getSheetByName("Questions").getDataRange().getValues()
```

So it reads from one file and writes to a different file. The script is set to run as a webapp as me, so on initial run, by default, this triggers a broad scope to view/edit/delete all sheets. I want to limit that. I see this is a scope I could manually set: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file ([docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)).

But I don't get how to then set my two spreadsheets as files that have been "opened or created" by the app so that the scope is valid for those files. I tried creating a function that creates two new sheets (I figured this counts as "a drive file that you created with this app") but even the `Spreadsheetapp.create()` function throws a "do not have permission" error.

I might be misunderstanding how this scoping works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

When `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` is used, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` is used. It seems that this is the current specification.

So, as a workaround, how about using Sheets API? When the Sheets API is used, you can use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

As an important point, the official document of the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is as follows.

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.

So, when you want to retrieve the data from the Spreadsheet using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, at first, the Spreadsheet is required to be created by the scope. In this answer, I would like to introduce the following flow.

1. Set the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to Google Apps Script project.
2. Create a new Spreadsheet.
3. Retrieve values from the Spreadsheet.

### Usage:

#### 1. Set scope.

Please create a new Google Apps Script. From your question, I understood that you are using the standalone type. For this, please set the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to the manifest file. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest) Please add `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]` to the file of `appsscript.json`. By this, the specific scope can be used.

#### 2. Create a new Spreadsheet.

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). When you run the following script, a new Spreadsheet is created and you can see the spreadsheet ID at the log. Please copy the ID. This ID is used in the next script. By this, a new Spreadsheet is created by the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

```js
function createNewSpreadsheet() {
  const id = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create({properties: {title: "sample"}}).spreadsheetId;
  console.log(id)
}
```

- When you try to retrieve the values from the existing Spreadsheet which is not created by this Google Apps Script project, an error of `Requested entity was not found.` occurs. So in this section, a new Spreadsheet is created by this Google Apps Script project.

#### 3. Get values from Spreadsheet.

Before you use this script, please open the created Spreadsheet and check the sheet name. And, as a sample, please put the sample values to the cells. When you run the following script, the values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet and you can see them at the log.

```js
function getValues() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the spreadsheet ID.
  const obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, "Sheet1");
  const values = obj.values;
  console.log(values)
}
```

### References:

- [Manifest structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest)
- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I basically followed that flow originally but my mistake was that I needed to switch to the Sheets API for the scope to apply correctly.